# MediaResponse Unable to play audio

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to play audio from Amazon in my action.

The media card shows as expected, but when I click the play the label "Loading ..." appears and after a few seconds give me the error "Unable to play audio".

If I use the audio from the Google example, it works fine, but mine does not.

I want to know if there is any specification about the file besides have an mp3 extension and stored in https location.

My code:

```
var podcast = new MediaObject ({
    name: 'Podicast Name # 08',
    url: 'https: //action_media_example_shortest.mp3',
    description: 'Description'
});
conv.ask(simpleResponse);
conv.ask(podcast);
conv.ask(suggestions);
```

The file was initially 1 hour, but I thought that was the problem, so I shrink it to 2 min, and the problem persists.

Comment: Since your URL is invalid, I can't test it to see if that may be the problem. If you update the example or provide a valid URL to test, we can see if that might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The audio can come from any valid, public, location. AWS is not a restriction (I've done it from AWS).

The most likely causes are:

- The bucket permissions don't actually allow the file to be public.
- The URL itself is invalid (your example URL is invalid in at least two ways).
- There are strange characters in the filename, which may require some encoding in the JSON.

You can test the first two by trying to load the URL in a browser tab that isn't logged into AWS (such as a chrome tab in incognito mode).